# Getting country having its city and language in php

Tags: php

I have a name of the city, let's say, it's "Londres" and the language it's written in: "French" in this case. It's just an example, there can be any languages and cities. What is the easiest way to get the country where there is such city, or the list of the countries?

Ideally, I want to get the country in the same language, i.e. in French in my case.

```
$city = "Londres";
$language = "FR";
// code for getting the city's country in French...
```

Comment: Do you have a database setup? Or are you asking us to find a data source and create code?

Comment: @nerdlyist Unfortunately, I don't have an idea where I can find a data source which would be appropriate for my purpose, that's why I'm asking

Comment: TBH I don't know that there is. Us developers do R&D this is the R part. Not trying to be rude this is just not really a question suited for SO.

Comment: @nerdlyist Of course, I did research, but failed to find what I need. I just need a piece of advice in what direction I should go, that's it

Comment: How do the language, country, and city relate? If you are looking for libraries/frameworks that is off topic for SO. Also questions seeking opinion answers are usually off topic.